# Im trying to find what I got wrong in simplifying

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question states " Simplify: $$\frac{6\left ( 27^{2n+3} \right )}{9^{3n+6}}$$

What I did was factoring $9$ and and $27$ to make it $3$. In the end I got a $\frac{6}{27}$ answer, simplified: $\frac{2}{9}$. but my problem is that in the book, the answer is stated as $\frac{27}{2}$. What could be the solution?

Comment: Perhaps you could show your work so we can see where your mistake was.

Comment: Either the answer in the book is wrong or perhaps you mistyped the question while copying from the book?

Comment: Special thanks to all who helped me. Ill be taking a college entrance exam tomorrow, wish me luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{6 \cdot27^{2n+3}}{9^{3n+6}}=\frac{2\cdot3\cdot[(3^3)]^{2n+3}}{(3^2)^{3n+6}}$$

$$=\frac{2\cdot3\cdot3^{6n+9}}{3^{6n+12}}=\frac{2\cdot3}{3^3}=\frac2{3^2}$$

Comment: This is my answer. The answer key's answer is 27/2 and I cant  figure out why.

Comment: @bie, I think, we should focus on the method. After all, to err is human

Answer (score 1):

$$27^{2n+3}=(3^3)^{2n+3}=3^{6n+9}$$ and $$9^{3n+6}=(3^2)^{3n+6}=3^{6n+12}$$

Comment: yeah thats what I got, then I continued. And got 2/9

Comment: @bie: See lab's post.